# Ошибка в функции GetFileSize: Types ... must be identical

Tags: delphi

```
function GetFileSize(const strFileName: String): Longint;
    var WFD: TWin32FindData; hFile: THandle;
    begin
    hFile := FindFirstFileA(PansiChar(strFileName), WFD);
    Result := WFD.nFileSizeLow;
    FindClose(hFile);
end;
```

не воспринимает эту строку:

```
  hFile := FindFirstFileA(PansiChar(strFileName), WFD);
```

Ошибка такого типа:

> `[DCC Error] Server.dpr(61): E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical`

Переменные вроде правильно объявил, есть какие мысли?

Answer (score 5):

Функция `FindFirstFileA` (ANSI вариант) требует `var` параметр типа `TWin32FindDataA` (тоже ANSI!).

У вас еще есть ошибка, но я оставлю её как упражнение :-)